# Service and Controller Methods Similar Operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a message service with operations like Create, List, Update and Delete.

In this Service I have a ListByMember(int memberId) method.

I need to build two Views, one to list with only the Title of the Message, and another View to List the Title and the Description of the message, and another to list the title and the total of the message answers already received.

I don't know if I create one method in the service layer and transport via DTO all the information from the message entity to the View and in the View I only show the fields that I want or if I create three methods in the service layer to be independent with it's own DTO's and to the specific View.

I'm afraid to create one single service method and if in the future I need a special list of the messages, I will face a problem.

Any advice would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Views /Controller actions are not the best place to put business logic. Try to have three methods at the service even if it means a little bit of additional code. You have decided to use DTOs to project that really good. One approach you may take is to create a private method to get the DTOs as IQueryable from the repository and expose it via public methods
As an example

```
// DTOs
public class MessageSummaryADto
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class MessageSummaryBDto : MessageSummaryADto
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

// public methods
public int GetMessageCount()
{
    return GetMessageSummary().Count();
}

public IQueryable<MessageSummaryADto> GetMessageSummaryADto()
{
    return GetMessageSummary().Select(m => new MessageSummaryADto { MessageId = m.MessageId, Title = m.Title });
}

public IQueryable<MessageSummaryBDto> GetMessageSummaryBDto()
{
    return GetMessageSummary();
}

// the private method
private IQueryable<MessageSummaryBDto> GetMessageSummary()
{
    return yourMessageRepository.Select(m =>
        new MessageSummaryBDto {
            MessageId = m.MessageId,
            Title = m.Title,
            Description = m.Description
        }
    );
}
```

If you are not a fan of IQueryable, you can expose the dtos as IList

Good luck

Comment: Hi thanks, so in your opinion for every DTO I have a Service Public Method that returns this DTO type? Another question btw, if you have a ViewModel that needs data of another entity, let say in a blog the blog comments, do you create a local class with the details of the coments you only need in the local viewmodel and build a list comment service method or you use the coments viewmodel that use the coments service method to do the list? I think that using the external coments class may limit changes in the future if I need aditional fields. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, If the concept of isolating comments of a blog is only needed at the views, I would create a DTO at the UI layer, then use a service which would return an IQueryable<Blog> to project it out within the controller action. If you have a separate service layer for UI, then you would want to move the model away from the UI to the UI service layer and do the projection there. I would love to post a code snippet to describe the concept, but the so-comments offers a limited number of characters

Comment: Hi, so if I understand you suggest Domain -> Service Method -> Map Domain to DTO -> Controller Action -> Map DTO to ViewModel -> View for every "line" of action I have this line, correct? You can edit your answer and complete it if you want. Thanks

Comment: BTW, do you have any example for a Create method that can receive different Models by parameter using the TPH approach?

Answer (score 0):

my second answer warrants for two levels of services, a business service and a UI service. You would want to have this approach if you have very specific UI processing such as projections and filters for things such as lists and grids. The business service will expose more generic methods, which would be neutral to the UI

So how it is mapped is;

**Domain objects (*output: Business Objects*)-> Business Service (*output generic DTOs*) -> UI Service (*UI specific DTOs*) -> Controller Action -> View**

Offloading the UI tasks of slicing and dicing of data to a UI specific service makes the Controller Action very thin (as it should be); generally it would be good if you can limit the number of lines of code in a controller action to a 10~15

Separating UI services from the code business services will make it easy for you to have multiple UIs. For example, when your business service is UI neutral, you may use it to carter to a ASP.Mvc and WPF app

Above approach comes with a price of additional layers to maintain, but if you want a clear separation, it’s worth considering

Cheers

Comment: Hi thanks, yes but as you say, it will come with a cost. I think the option here is to have 1 service method for each DTO. Thanks again